# Python - Mouse data

Tags: python, python-2.7, mouse

I am trying to get movement data from the mouse using python 2.7. Is there any way to do it?
I want to get displacement in inches or mm and also its direction. I want x,y values so i can represent it on x,y plane. In case there is no such way to do it, can you tell me how to extract the raw data and use it to calculate displacement and direction?

Please remember that i want to extract the data by using only python 2.7.

Comment: `using only python 2.7` means no external library?

Comment: If you wish to do this without any external libraries you will need to specify your Operating System and your mouse hardware.

Comment: any libraries it supports, by that i meant i wanna use only 2.7 version of python(IDLE)

Comment: it would be very easy to store mouse movement using pygame.  Do you want to actively show the movement on screen or just save it to plot later?

Comment: lets say mouse moves 10 mm, i want to print out the displacement , how much it has moved and in which direction like in angles or something. Note: i want readings regardless cursor position. i mean when the cursor is on the extreme left it cant move any farther but mouse can move and it still sends some data,i want that data, i wanna see how much mouse has displaced from its previous position.
pygame only detects how much the cursor has moved but it doesnt give info about the mouse displacement.

Comment: I want readings from the sensor. is there any way to get the info which window uses to determine the cursor position. Again, i dont wanna deal with cursor, i want data from the sensor

Answer (score 0):

Take look at PyUserInput library [PyUserInput on Github](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) for getting mouse (x,y) coordinates. But displacment you will have calculate yourself. Ie, save previous x,y and calculate displacement (in pixels) with new x,y values.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the PyAutoGUI module from PyPI (run `pip install pyautogui`) and then call the `pyautogui.position()` to get the X and Y coordinates of the mouse:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.position()
(553, 792)
```

PyAutoGUI works on Windows, Mac, and Linux, and on Python 2 and 3.